# Button not highlighting when pressed

Tags: objective-c, ipad, click, highlighting

I have plenty buttons in my application that get highlighted when they are pressed, though I have a few I have added to a slide down menu which oddly do not highlight on button press.

"Highlighted Adjusts Image" is selected, and I have also tried

> quickYes.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES

But this isn't highlighting the selected button when pressed either.
Could anyone advise as to why this is happening? 
This is the code for my menu below (I'm not sure whether any code in here has influence on it's highlighting?):

```
 -(IBAction)OpenMenu:(id)sender {
    if (draw1 ==0) {
        draw1 = 1;
        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 120);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(708, 120, 265, 75);
        oSmallLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 127, 60, 30);
        quickYes.frame = CGRectMake(20, 10, 99, 96);
        quickNo.frame = CGRectMake(148, 10, 99, 96);
        quickHello.frame = CGRectMake(278, 10, 99, 96);
        quickBye.frame = CGRectMake(409, 10, 99, 96);
        quickThankYou.frame = CGRectMake(539, 10, 99, 96);
        [openMenu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    } else {
        draw1 = 0;
        [UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIButton setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIButton setAnimationDelay:0.0];
        [UIButton setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
        scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -120, 1024, 120);
        openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(708, 0, 265, 75);
        oSmallLabel.frame = CGRectMake(20, 2, 60, 30);
        quickYes.frame = CGRectMake(20, -99, 99, 96);
        quickNo.frame = CGRectMake(148, -99, 99, 96);
        quickHello.frame = CGRectMake(278, -99, 99, 96);
        quickBye.frame = CGRectMake(409, -120, 99, 96);
        quickThankYou.frame = CGRectMake(539, -99, 99, 96);
        [openMenu setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollView];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
    }
```